# MySQL reverts changes to decimal datatype back to original

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a MySQL decimal column currently set to 6,3.  (InnoDB if that matters)

```
products_weight` decimal(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
```

I change that to 15,4 (15,5 would be better) and the default to 0.0000

I amend some values in the columns to have 4 decimal places.

Those changes remain in place for a while.

A short while later the column changes back to 6,3 and the previously amended values are replaced with 0.  Only the values I changed to have 4 decimals (0.0001 for example) change to 0, existing values which aren't changed remain unaltered.  For further clarification, I only need to change 12 values which were previously 0 to 0.0001

There is another decimal column in the same table that is already defined as 15,4 and this has no problems, only when I change an existing field length and decimal.

There is nothing in the web code base making this reversion.  Any ideas?

Comment: *A short while later the column changes back to 6,3 and the previously amended values are replaced with 0* ALL values in a table? ALL values inserted after datatype change? SOME values inserted after datatype change?

Comment: Possible scenario - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65d01100641d00387ee355b16bb8e451) (not zeros, simple demonstration that datatype change may be reverted with data damage).

Comment: @Akina good question!  Only the ones I changed to have 4 decimals 0.0001 for example.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @Akina, when I say the column changes back to 6,3, I mean the actual column definition changes from 15,4 to 6,3 with no intervention.  I did wonder if it could have been rounding when it does that, but when it does it inserts 0 (no decimals) and not 0.000 which is the default value.

Comment: For `DECIMAL(6,3)` default value `0` and `0.000` is absolutely the same, no difference. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04f6654446aed9d5f00bab56b9b7dce5). *I mean the actual column definition changes from 15,4 to 6,3 with no intervention.* This is impossible. Only explicit ALTER TABLE can alter column definition. So search where this ALTER TABLE was executed from - replication, event, restore, manually, ...

Comment: Can you provide a test case that exhibits the actions you describe?  (I seriously believe this is a user error.)